# Is the use of blank interfaces a bad design?

Tags: design-patterns, interface

I'm considering creating an interface and applying it to all objects in a certain namespace.

Scenario in which I would use this:  I want to create a generic handler of those objects, and I'd like to enforce the generic parameter to only accept types that implement this particular interface.

Is this a bad design, or are blank interfaces acceptable?

Comment: Repeat? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3162214/456188

Comment: @Cpfohl: My question does seem to be very similar to the one you link to.  It seems this other question is more obscurely written (check the 'viewed' count), and less well covered in the responses.

Comment: Not tellin' you you have to take it down! :) I'm just pointing it out in case you get any extra info from it.

Comment: Your scenario seems like a perfect fit for the visitor pattern. Instead of making all your classes implement a an empty interface, consider adding an `accept` method to each of them, and create a visitor/handler interface that has a `visit`/`handle` method for each of the particular classes that you wish to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about doing is known as [Marker Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

I've used this technique successfully in the past, but I would question whether the artificial limitation you are placing on your generic class is actually necessary.  If so, then this is certainly a quick and compile checked method of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not bad design. Providing reasonable constraints on generic arguments helps maintain code safety and readability. Furthermore, you can be quite sure the interface won't remain empty forever.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with them in my opinion. A lot of their strength lies in combination with (generated) partial classes.

Answer (score 1):

My personal understanding of an interface is that it forms the public contract between one or more objects. The idea is simple, you can build your code base up using interfaces without worrying about implementation. Having said that it is an interesting question because you are technically trying to inforce a contract. I would say go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating this interface if it's blank? What are the contents of each class? Is there *any* commonality between them? If the answer to that question is no, then why are you making an interface for each?

If you have a good reason for making a blank interface, it's probably alright. But think about it and see whether you can put anything into that interface that is common between the elements.

Comment: ... At the same time I would not inforce extra information into an interface just for the sake of it. The less loosely defined and interface is the better. You could always use multiple interfaces for extra functional obligations.

Comment: I wouldn't make an interface for each, just one interface that covers all objects within a certain namespace.  And, the assumption in my question is that there is not commonality between them, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing... Wrong with using a blank interface, I guess. Just, the point of an interface is to define a common set of functionality that may vary in how its implemented.

It won't make coding any easier, since you're effectively working with a black-box (`object`, as some may call it).

Honestly, though, if I were implementing such an open ended architecture, I'd just go with regular old `object`.